# Como verificar se uma matriz contém um valor específico?

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
const role = tokenPayload.params.role.map(r => {
  return r.value;
}) [0];
```

Ela retorna isso:

```
author
```

Se eu retirar o index [0], retorna isso:

```
["author", "admin"]
```

É possível que a função retorne todos os valores no mesmo formato do primeiro exemplo? O "role" const será usado em uma comparação === que aceita apenas o resultado nesse formato específico.

Vou colocar a função completa para melhor compreensão:

```
canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    const helper = new JwtHelperService();
    const expectedRole = route.data.expectedRole;
    const token = this.authService.getToken();
    const tokenPayload = helper.decodeToken(token);
    const role: string = tokenPayload.params.role.map(r => {
  return r.value;
}) [0];
console.log(role);
if (!this.authService.isAuthenticated() || role !== expectedRole) {
  this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
  return false;
}
return true;
}
```

router component:

```
{
    path: 'container-users',
    component: ContainerUsersComponent,
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    data: {
      expectedRole: 'admin'
    },
    children: [
      { path: '', component: ListUsersComponent },
      { path: 'list-users', component: ListUsersComponent },
      { path: 'form-new-user', component: FormNewUserComponent }
    ]
  }
```

No momento, eu estou passando somente uma função por usuário. Porém, gostaria de deixar o código dinâmico, para caso algum usuário tenha mais que uma função futuramente.

Comment: Questão respondida aqui: [How to transform the value of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51938215/9509575)

Answer (score 0):

Tire o `[0]`.

Assim:

```
const roles = tokenPayload.params.role.map(r => {
  return r.value;
});

console.log(roles);
```

O `[0]` está fazendo você pegar o primeiro valor do array gerado pelo `map`.

Veja o meu exemplo:

```js
const usuarios = [{nome: "Wallace"}, {nome: "Wayne"}]

console.log(usuarios.map( function (u) {
   return u.nome; 
}));

console.log(usuarios.map( function (u) {
   return u.nome; 
})[0]);
```

Comment: Eu preciso que os valores venham igual ao primeiro print, ou seja, fora do array. É possível? Tipo [author, admin] e não ["author","admin"].

Comment: Assim? `var author = roles[0]; var admin= roles[1];`

Comment: o valor que essa função retornar vai ser comparado usando "===" com um string. Vou colocar a função que usa o valor role:

if (!this.authService.isAuthenticated() || role !== expectedRole) {
      this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
      return false;
    }

só funciona se colocar o [0] na primeira função, com a resposta retornando do jeito do primeiro print, que é o role. Só que pode acontecer de o usuário ter mais de uma função, se colocar o [0], só retorna a 1a função. Preciso que retorne todas, mas do jeito que vem no primeiro print.

Desculpe se parece boba a pergunta.

Comment: Você não colocou nenhuma dessas informações na sua pergunta. Era essencial que tivesse feito isso antes da resposta. Por favor, edite sua pergunta e coloque todas as informações que você deseja.

Comment: Eu expliquei na pergunta o que preciso, que é que o valor retornado venha no mesmo formato do primeiro print. Desculpe, mas acredito que a minha pergunta está completa, pq realmente só preciso saber como retornar o valor naquele formato. Agradeço se vc puder me ajudar, mas se não puder, agradeço do mesmo jeito.